# How can I make my navigation menu copy across all pages locally and on a server

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, my navigation menu copies across all my pages fine, but it only works when it's on a server. It's not working locally.

Right now I have a nav.html page that contains the code for my navigation menu. Then I include `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` in my sites head.

After that, I include `<div id="nav-placeholder"></div> $(function(){$("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");});` in my sites body. This works fine when tested on a server, but not locally. How can I get it to also work locally?

Comment: "How can I get it to also work locally?" locally means you call the page in a browser from a locally server or just in a browser from from the local filesystem?

Comment: I'm calling the page from the local filesystem